# the example code in Dive into Python 3

Tags: python

I am reading Mark Pilgrim's Dive into Python 3. He gave the "nirvana" code for pluralizing a noun. My question is: are the codes in line 30 & 31 necessary? It seems the program works fine without them. What's the benefit of adding them? Thank you

```
    import re
    def build_match_and_apply_functions(pattern, search, replace):
        def matches_rule(word):
            return re.search(pattern, word)
        def apply_rule(word):
            return re.sub(search, replace, word)
        return (matches_rule, apply_rule)

def plural(noun):
    for matches_rule, apply_rule in rules:
        if matches_rule(noun):
            return apply_rule(noun)
    raise ValueError('no matching rule for {0}'.format(noun))

class LazyRules:
    rules_filename = 'plural6-rules.txt'
    def __init__(self):
        self.pattern_file = open(self.rules_filename, encoding='utf-8')
        self.cache = []

    def __iter__(self):
        self.cache_index = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.cache_index += 1
        if len(self.cache) >= self.cache_index:
            return self.cache[self.cache_index - 1]

##Line 30:        if self.pattern_file.closed:
##Line 31:            raise StopIteration

        line = self.pattern_file.readline()
        if not line:
            self.pattern_file.close()
            raise StopIteration

        pattern, search, replace = line.split(None, 3)
        funcs = build_match_and_apply_functions(pattern, search, replace)
        self.cache.append(funcs)
        return funcs

rules = LazyRules()
nouns=['fox', 'horse', 'cheetah','ad', 'quay', 'vacancy']
for noun in nouns:
    print (noun)
    print(plural(noun)+'\n')

## plural6-rules.txt:
##[sxz]$ $ es
##[^aeioudgkprt]h$ $ es
##[^aeiou]y$ y$ ies
##$   $   s
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those lines are necessary, as the [book explains](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.2/diveintopython3/html/iterators.html#autopre13) (see note 2).

In the previous iteration, the pattern file may have already been closed.

By raising `StopIteration`, a for loop will exit gracefully (see [note 5](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.2/diveintopython3/html/iterators.html#autopre6))

If you don't `raise StopIteration` the next line will try to read from a closed file.

```
line = self.pattern_file.readline()
```

This would cause a `ValueError`.

To demonstrate when those lines would run, try removing the final line of your `plural6-rules.txt` file (which matches everything), then type the following.

```
>>> from plural6 import plural
>>> plural("fox") # matches the first rule
'foxes'
>>> plural("foo") # does not match any rules. file is closed.
>>> plural("foo") # We have removed the check, we will try to read from a closed file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "plural6.py", line 50, in plural
    for matches_rule, apply_rule in rules:
  File "plural6.py", line 36, in __next__
    line = self.pattern_file.readline()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Comment: Can you give me an example when these two lines will be executed? I have commented the lines out, they seemed to be working fine.

Comment: I've added an example. You'll have to edit the rules file to remove the catch all rule.

Answer (score -1):

They are not needed, because the code just a few lines down (which closes the file when `readline()` returns an empty string, indicating the end of the file) raises `StopIteration` then. There's no situation in which the file would be closed from a *previous* iteration. Well, I guess if you kept calling `next()` on it after the file was closed, but the code you're using doesn't do that.

That code is, generally speaking, awful. Is this typical for that book? If so, throw it away and try another.

Comment: It's possible for code outside that method to close the file between iteration steps. Although there's nothing in this example that would do that, it's a reasonable thing to consider if you were just implementing the class.

Comment: In that case it would be much better handled by `try/except` and just raise `StopIteration` when you get an `IOError`. But no, people should not do stupid things like close a file out from under an object that obviously uses it. "You're gonna have a bad time."

Comment: It's not code outside the method between iteration steps that we're worried about, it's subsequent iterations. Consider the following: `rules = LazyRules(); [r for r in rules]; [r for r in rules];` The file is closed at the end of the first list comprehension. Without the check for the closed file, the second list comprehension will raise `ValueError`.